# Solve $\min_{\mathbf{x}} \sum_i \min\left[ (\mathbf{c}_i^T\mathbf{x}-a_i)^2, (\mathbf{d}_i^T\mathbf{x}-b_i)^2 \right]$

Tags: least-squares, quadratic-programming

I am wondering if there is an efficient (perhaps closed form) way to solve the following piecewise quadratic minimisation problem:
$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}}
\sum_{i=1}^n \min\left[ (\mathbf{c}_i^T\mathbf{x}-a_i)^2, (\mathbf{d}_i^T\mathbf{x}-b_i)^2 \right]
$$
It is a combination of linear least squares problems where there are two possible solutions for each $i$ and we would like to take the smaller of the two.

I can see that one approach would be to solve all possible combinations of the two terms as separate linear least squares problems. E.g. solve:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{c}_1^T \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{c}_n^T
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\
\vdots \\
a_n \end{bmatrix},\ \  
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{d}_1^T \\
\mathbf{c}_2^T \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{c}_n^T
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
a_2 \\ 
\vdots \\
a_n \end{bmatrix},\ \ \dots\ \ \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{d}_1^T \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{d}_n^T
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
\vdots \\
b_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
and take the solution with minimal residual. However, there will be $2^n$ such systems to solve so if $n$ is large this may not be practical.

I'm actually interested solving a particular version of this problem where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathrm{R}^3$ and the following conditions hold:
$$
\forall i, \|\mathbf{c}_i\|=\|\mathbf{d}_i\|=1 \land \mathbf{c}_i = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{d}_i \land a_i = b_i>0
$$
If I plug my problem into a nonlinear least squares optimiser (lsqnonlin in Matlab), it quickly converges to (one of) the global optima (for my particular problem there are two global optima) regardless of initialisation. I've also noticed that the two global optima are related by:
$$
\mathbf{x}_1^* = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_2^*
$$
I would like to gain some more insight into the problem. What is the best way to go about solving this problem? Although seemingly nonconvex, why does lsqnonlin always converge to one of the two global optima?

Comment: I don't think the overall objective is convex since the minimum of two convex functions is not convex.

Comment: you are right, my bad, that obective function is not convex at all. I'm wondering now if there is an algorithm to find the solution in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ quadratic minimizations (instead of $n^2$).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is NP-hard. Note that you have $n$ binary choices to make, and these binary choices (choosing the minimum for each $i$) need to be made collectively.

Therefore, there are $2^n$ possible least-squares problems that need to be solved, and you'll have to choose one of them that gives you the global minimum.

However, if you had a $\max$ operator inside your summation, then you would have a convex optimization program with quadratic constrains, that could also be formulated as semi-definite program (SDP) (which is also convex, and can be solved efficiently.)  I see that you have a different objective though.

Comment: Ok, some additional detail on my particular version of this problem (that may explain the two global optima). My $\mathbf{c}_i$ and $\mathbf{d}_i$ are related to each other by:

Comment: $$\mathbf{c}_i=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{d}_i$$ Does this special structure have some implication for reducing the complexity? As I say, I obtain one of the two global optima using lsqnonlin in Matlab so it must be convex within the two subspaces that lead to the two global minima.

Comment: Finally, the two global minima are also related to each other by: $$\mathbf{x}_1^*=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}_2^*$$

Comment: The professional way is to acknowledge when you use some body's answer to improve your question. But, I leave it to your judgment.